# Unnecessary callback usage in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, nonblocking

I'm learning node.js and I got most of the fundamentals down about asynchronous non-blocking I/O.  My question is what's the point of creating a function with callbacks when the function itself isn't asynchronous.  Even if the function you are creating has a call to an asynchronous function, I can't find a reason why you'd use a callback.  I see this a lot in the node.js code i'm looking at.

For example, a function that sends an HTTP request and returns the parsed output of the request:

```
function withCallback(url, callback) {
  request(url, function(err, response, html) {
    if (err)
      callback(err, null);
    callback(null, JSON.parse(html));
  });
}

function withoutCallback(url) {
  request(url, function(err, response, html) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    return JSON.parse(html);
  });
}
```

The first function with a callback returns the result through a callback while the second function just returns it normally.

Comment: Mostly, it's because the second one won't work.

Comment: The return in the second function cannot be captured, so that data is lost.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz it simply cannot work.

Comment: you can't return from a callback, so if you need a value back, you must pass a function to accept it.

Comment: @Pointy I thought I was able to return from a callback but I must have made a mistake.  Is the only way to return a result from inside a callback through a callback? Thanks for the responses and clearing things up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was going to write as a comment, but went a bit too long.

You are asking a couple of questions. To address the very correct point that the commenters make, the second example just won't work and as @Hawkings states more clearly, the result can't be captured (by your code). It won't work because the `return` in the second example the anonymous function you are creating (the actual callback being passed to `request`) is being invoked and returning its result deep within the `request` function. Also, in your example, control would have already returned to the caller of `withoutCallback` well before that `return JSON.parse()` line gets called, and as written, `foo = withoutCallback(...)` would result in `foo` being undefined.

If you look at the code for a library that uses callbacks you will see how these are invoked and it may make more sense why this isn't going to work. (Although I would suggest looking at a simpler library than request - if you are fairly new to node, I think you will find the request library to be a a bit confusing).

However, in the case of what you state your question is (which is not illustrated in your examples): "My question is what's the point of creating a function with callbacks when the function itself isn't asynchronous[?]"

There is not much point in that particular circumstance unless a) you want to future proof it in case it may become asynchronous because of added functionality or b) you want to have a common interface in which other implementations would be asynchronous. To use a browser example just because it comes readily to mind, if you were implementing a generic basic data storage solution, one implementation of which would use LocalStorage (synchronous) but others which might use IndexedDB, or a remote call (both asynchronous) - you would still want to write the LocalStorage implementation using callbacks so you could easily switch among the implementations.

If you don't like the callback style, consider learning to work with, and use libraries that make use of, other techniques or language features for handling asynchronicity, including Promises, Generators or in applicable cases, EventEmitters. I am personally a big fan of Promises. Having said that, I wouldn't suggest any of those until you get your head around the hows and whys of callbacks.